# Проблемы совместимости: ищу помощь для открытия .cdr файла на Mac

Tags: reactjs, mac, corel-draw

Заказчик прислал дизайн сайта в .cdr. Однако при открытии на Mac возникли проблемы:

[image]

В то время как на Windows всё в порядке.
Проблемы совместимости не решились изменением версий CorelDraw и пересохранением файла.

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным, буду благодарен за помощь. Не хочу переходить на написание кода на Windows, предпочитаю работать на Mac.

P.S. я уже пробовал сохранять в формате пдф, и да, таким образом оно работает, но слишком мало информации выходит в итоге.

Comment: Это жесть. Переношу свои же файлы с винды на мак. Сегодня потратила полдня, чтобы открыть один файл. Судя по всему, это воля случая. Неудивительно, что корел проигрывает Адоби, уже как бы я его ни любила. Просто большая часть файлов с текстом, созданных под виндой, не хочет открываться на маке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился сам собой;) Поставил при пересохранении файла с винды минимально доступную версию, а это была 15.0. Так что, надеюсь, что помог кому-то собственным вопросом с собственным ответом. Сейчас всё сохранилось как надо.

Comment: Проверил на остальных версиях, всё, что идёт дальше 15.0, уже не работает. Если вдруг у кого-то будет схожая проблема со шрифтами, то просто пересохраните файл с пк на виндоусе и выберите там версию 15.0. Другого варианта решения данной проблемы я не нашёл.